# Determine if user tapped a date in ion-datetime vs change month

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

In an Ionic 6 `ion-datetime` I want to react when a user picks a date, not when they change month using the wheel view. It's ok that they use the wheel view to jump forward many months, or years, but I don't want run my code unless they tap on a specific date in that month. I can't determine any difference in the event between a user pressing the forward button a few times to move from Jan to May, then selecting May 1st, compared to a user opening the month selecting and scrolling to May and stopping the scroll there. At this point they have not said what day in May they want, so I expect them to select the month, close the month panel and tap on 1-31.

An acceptable option for me to be to remove the month picker altogether and force them to use the next/previous month button because they are unlikely to need to skip a year ahead